# Confusion with parallel vector definition.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Two non-zero vectors $x$ and $y$ are said to be parallel if there exists a non-zero scalar $\lambda$ such that $x=\lambda y $.

Here is my stupid question: I don't understand this definition in $\mathbb{R^2}$ or $\mathbb{R^3}$. If $x$ is a scalar multiple of $y$, then how are they parallel? In $\mathbb{R^2}$, isn't $y$ contained in $x$ since they're scalar multiples? So they're lines with direction, but they share part of the same line. So how are they parallel if they have points in common with each other? I'm thinking the same thing in $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: A vector is not a line.  For each vector, there are an infinite many number of directed line segments that represent that vector.  For any vector $\vec V$, we can create a directed line segment that begins at a point, say $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, and ends at another point, $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+1\,\vec V$.

Comment: I don't believe this definition is correct, as the [zero vector is parallel to all vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909952/convention-regarding-zero-vector) even though it doesn't meet your definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vector, in an elementary sense, is a magnitude and a direction. Two vectors are parallel if they have the same direction. Vectors are not lines or line segments. They are not sets, and therefore cannot contain one another. Vectors also are not points in the plane, nor do they contain points in the plane. This may seem strange to you as a vector is often represented as an arrow drawn on the plane, but a vector is actually a more abstract object.

I imagine you are thinking of the geometric definition of parallel lines, which is that two lines in $\mathbb R^n$ are parallel if they do not intersect, or if they intersect an infinite number of times. Since vectors are not lines, this definition does not apply, and we use a new definition, which is the one you gave.

Comment: I am thinking of parallel lines in the plane. I guess I don't understand why two vectors are parallel if they are scalar multiples. That isn't clear to me.

Comment: @AlexS  +1 I just left a comment that discusses the distinction between a vector and a representation of a vector via a directed line segment.   Well done!

Comment: @1233dfv Well, part of it is that parallel means "going in the same direction." The only way vectors can have the same direction is if they are scalar multiples of each other. The rest of it is that because vectors are a completely different objects, so we are free do redefine the word parallel for them however we want, even if it has nothing to do with other meanings of the word. I can think of at least four definitions of "normal" in math, each applying to different objects, and each completely different in nature.

Comment: I see. So when someone says parallel line or parallel vector the meaning of the word "parallel" in both concepts is different. So my problem is I'm using the meaning of parallel in the concept parallel lines and applying it to parallel vectors and it's giving me issues. Is that what's going on?

Comment: Yes. Again, in this case there is some crossover in the definition. Parallel vectors can be described as having the same direction, just like parallel lines. But at the end on the day, you cannot compare apples and oranges.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I think I understand this now.